# Bot framework policies in pdf and word documents

Tags: botframework

We are automating our internal policies using Chat BOT. Most of the policies are in pdfs and word documents, what is the best way to store data for responses ? To extract content from documents and store in databases or any other way ? Because in each document there are many possible questions users can ask.

Answer (score 0):

One way is if you look into MS's Cognitive Service called **QnA Maker**.

- What is QnA Maker [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/overview/overview).
- Sample Bot implementing QnA Maker [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/11.qnamaker).